# JSON API (created in PHP) does not return results when requested

Tags: php, json, api, callback, jsonp

I have a JSON API created in PHP which returns

```
?({"a":"b"})
```

when I type

```
"http://mylink.php?callback=?"
```

in the browser. But when I give the same link from a desktop app (using $.ajax) the results are not returned. The PHP code which creates the JSON API is

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); // Also tried application/json
    $results = array();
    $results['a'] = 'b';
    $encoded = json_encode($results);
    $encoded_callback = '?' . '(' . $encoded . ')';
    echo $encoded_callback;
    return $encoded_callback;
?>
```

The javascript code only contains

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success:function(data){
            ... some printing ...                
        }        
    });
```

up to know and **it works fine when I tried it with another JSON API (not created by me). So I assume that the problem lies in my API.**

What is wrong? I feel that something is missing so that the communication can be held but I don't know what and on which side (server or client).

Comment: If you're saying that it doesn't work in your frontend JS, it would be nice to at least show it to us.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov I edited my post and added the JS code. Let me point out though that the reason why I had not included it is that the same code works fine when I try requesting a different JSON API (not created by me, and not in PHP). So I have the strong belief that the problem lies in my API and not in the JS code. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $encoded_callback = '?' . '(' . $encoded . ')';
> ```

`?` *isn't a valid function name* in JavaScript (it is [an operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12)). You should put the function name specified in the callback parameter there (which isn't `?`, the `?` tells jQuery to generate a unique name).

```
$encoded_callback = $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $encoded . ')';
```

---

Better yet: Stop using JSONP. It is a hack to get around the same origin policy which limits you in many ways (including only allowing GET requests and making your API public instead of being able to restrict it to specific origins).

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) provides a non-hacky, entirely standard approach for cross-origin requests and you should use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. First of all, the link I request will always have '?' as a callback parameter as it is stable (like a constant) in the program. So the server knows that it will always use '?' as a callback function. Secondly, I have tried requesting a different API (not created by me) with callback "?" and it works fine. So I assume the problem is in my API. Last, I have also tried CORS instead of JSONP but the problem remains the same :/ I will keep in mind that it is a better practice, however I would first like to make the whole thing work...

Comment: Do you mean that I should use "$_GET['callback']" instead of "?" even if I know that the callback will always be "?" ?

Comment: @Marievi — "will always have '?' as a callback parameter as it is stable (like a constant) in the program" — No you won't. As I explained in the answer, jQuery will generate a unique name to replace it.

Comment: @Marievi — "I have tried requesting a different API (not created by me) with callback "?" and it works fine." — That's because jQuery replaced it with a valid name and the server side code *you didn't write* used the name it was given by jQuery instead of hardcoding `?` which is not a valid function name.

Comment: @Marievi — "Do you mean that I should use "$_GET['callback']" instead of "?" " — Yes, I even wrote the code to demonstrate that in the answer.

Comment: I am sorry if I made a pointless question but I had not understood that "?" is not stable even if I give it manually. Thanks a lot for your help, I will try it.